# How can I install latest VLC player in CentOS 6.4?

Tags: linux, centos, vlc

I have installed CentOS 6.4 in my laptop, I want to know the method of installing VLC in CentOS 6.4, Is it necessary to download the vlc package and compile or can I use `yum install vlc` to install the same ?

Comment: a simple visit to VLC site answers your question ... you need to add the repo or download the rpm and then install with yum localinstal "rpmfile"

Answer (score 5):

You can install the following yum repositories (EPEL, famillecollet, & RPMFusion) so that you can install VLC:

```
$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch.rpm
```

Now test to see if you see the VLC package:

```
$ yum --enablerepo=remi-test info vlc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Available Packages
Name        : vlc
Arch        : i686
Version     : 2.0.3
Release     : 1.el6
Size        : 1.9 M
Repo        : rpmfusion-free-updates
Summary     : The cross-platform open-source multimedia framework, player and server
URL         : http://www.videolan.org
License     : GPLv2+
Description : VLC media player is a highly portable multimedia player and multimedia framework
            : capable of reading most audio and video formats as well as DVDs, Audio CDs VCDs,
            : and various streaming protocols.
            : It can also be used as a media converter or a server to stream in uni-cast or
            : multi-cast in IPv4 or IPv6 on networks.
```

Update the system before installing vlc

```
$ sudo yum update -y
```

To install it:

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-test install vlc
```

To test it:

```
$ vlc
```