# broken filesets after install VLC via RPMFusion

Tags: yum, centos, vlc

Needed a media player, followed the link on this [site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83637/how-can-i-install-latest-vlc-player-in-cent-os-6-4)

Here is the last part of the YUM output;

```
After following the link above, VLC installed and executed fine, but I was left with broken filesets and now my updates won't install.

Error: Package: libquicktime-1.2.4-1.el6.rf.i686 (@rpmforge)
       Requires: libx264.so.107
       Removing: x264-0.0.0-0.4.20101111.el6.rf.i686 (@rpmforge)
           libx264.so.107
       Updated By: x264-0.120-5.20120303.el6.i686 (rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I'm digging CentOS, Ubuntu worked ok untill 13.10 where the 3D played havoc with my NVIDIA card and desktop.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the output, x264 is provided by 2 repos you have enabled, rpmforge and rpmfusion, and those packages conflict. You need to choose either of the two (try disabling rpmfusion first), or exclude the conflicting package(s) in /etc/yum.conf